# Unity NavmeshComponent (Unable to bake navmesh)

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

I'm pretty new to Unity and im working on a duo project with my friend. He is generating a city with L-system, with prefabs made in MagicaVoxel, and I'm trying to populate the city with pedestrians and make them walk randomly.

I have the NavMeshComponents from git, and my problem is i can't bake the navmesh on runtime because the objects (roads houses etc.) are instantiated and pieced together on runtime. All the tutorials I've seen had object before running so they could put the navmeshsurface on it, but in this case i can't. Is there a solution for this or i should try to find a different approach? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

To use the navmesh baking at runtime you need to **create a empty GameObject that holds a NavMeshSurface component.**

Then in your script, access that component and bake it whenever you need

```
using Unity.AI.Navigation
void BakeAtRuntime() 
{
   GetComponent<NavMeshSurface>().BuildNavMesh();
}
```